# Remap values in a dataframe where the key is one column and the value to be replaced is another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary which is a mapping of id's to correct names for a company.
say the dict is `correct_names = {1: 'fixed_name', 2:'fixed_name1}`

I would like to apply it to a dataframe similar to:

```
        ID     name_col
0       1      name
1       2      name1
2       3      name2
3       4      name3
```

So it goes in and fixes all the bad company names.

```
        ID     name_col
0       1      fixed_name
1       2      name1
2       3      fixed_name1
3       4      name3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
correct_names = {1: 'fixed_name', 2:'fixed_name1'}
df.name_col = df.ID.map(correct_names).combine_first(df.name_col)
#alternative solution
#df.name_col = df.ID.map(correct_names).fillna(df.name_col)
print (df)
   ID     name_col
0   1   fixed_name
1   2  fixed_name1
2   3        name2
3   4        name3
```

Another solution:

```
df = pd.Series(correct_names)
       .combine_first(df.set_index('ID').name_col)
       .rename_axis('ID')
       .reset_index(name='name_col')
print (df)
   ID     name_col
0   1   fixed_name
1   2  fixed_name1
2   3        name2
3   4        name3
```